# Facebook account with a Gmail email address

Tags: gmail, facebook, account-management

When I am on my Facebook account with a Gmail email address, will Gmail notify me at what time I have accessed my Facebook account?

Answer (score 6):

The two are unrelated; it’s not Gmail that sends the message, but Facebook. To turn this feature on, go to **Account Setting** → **Security** → **Login Notifications**.

However, there is a caveat: it only works for new devices, that you haven’t used to connect to Facebook before.

> We can notify you when your account is accessed from a computer or mobile device that you haven't used before